# Vagrant (Saltstack) how to install package.json with salt state?

Tags: json, node.js, vagrant, vagrantfile, salt-stack

I want to install my environment with vagrant "vagrant up". I made code to install modules but I want to install package.json files and how? my modules installer code looks like that:

```
mongodb:
  pkg:
    - installed
  service:
    - running

nodejs:
  pkg:
    - installed

npm:
  pkg:
    - installed

git:
  pkg:
    - installed

build-essential:
  pkg:
    - installed

bower:
  npm:
    - installed

nodemon:
  npm:
    - installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a state for that [npm.bootstrap](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2014.7/ref/states/all/salt.states.npm.html#salt.states.npm.bootstrap)

Ex:

```
my-deps:
  npm.bootstrap:
    - name: /vagrant
    - user: vagrant
    - require:
      - pkg: nodejs
```

this

> will execute npm install --json on the specified directory